# Versiones Python instaladas

Tags: python, python-3.x

Buenos días compañeros,

tengo instaladas varias versiones de Python por lo que los módulos se me instalan solo para la versión de la consola o la versión "por defecto".

Como puedo cambiar estos valores??? Gracias!!!

Answer (score 2):

Cada versión de python es "independiente" de las demás. El ejecutable `python` de cada una de ellas está en su propia carpeta, y en esa carpeta están también los módulos que vayas instalando.

La forma más sencilla de instalar un paquete para una versión particular, es usar el intérprete de esa versión particular, en la forma siguiente:

1. Averigua la ruta hasta el ejecutable del intérprete. Es decir, supongamos que quieres instalar un paquete para python3.8. Buscas en qué carpeta está instalado el ejecutable `python` para esa versión. Digamos que lo tienes en `/usr/bin/python3.8` (o si estás en Windows podría ser por ejemplo `C:/Users/TuUsuario/Anaconda3/python.exe`)
2. Ejecuta el siguiente comando, poniendo la ruta absoluta apropiada hacia tu intérprete:

   ```
   /ruta/absoluta/hasta/python -m pip install paquete
   ```

Eso usará el módulo `pip` de esa versión particular de python para instalar el paquete, por lo que quedará instalado en esa versión particular.

### Bonus

No es muy buena idea de todas formas instalar paquetes "globalmente" pues a veces diferentes proyectos en los que puedas estar trabajando (con esa misma versión de python) pueden necesitar diferentes versiones de un mismo paquete.

Te recomiendo usar entornos virtuales. Un entorno virtual es como otra instalación adicional de python, pero en una carpeta de usuario que tú elijas. Dentro de esa carpeta tendrás una versión de python "independiente" de las que estén instaladas en el sistema (aunque antes necesitas tener una en el sistema, pues de ahí será copiada). Podrás instalar paquetes en ese entorno virtual sin afectar a la instalación del sistema ni a otros entornos virtuales.

Se crean así:

```
/ruta/absoluta/hasta/python -m venv /ruta/a/la/carpeta/que/quieras
```

Eso creará la `/ruta/a/la/carpeta/que/quieras/` y dentro de ella sub carpetas `bin`, `lib`, etc. con su propia instalación python.

Una vez creado el entorno virtual lo "activas" con el comando (en unix, bash):

```
source /ruta/a/la/carpeta/que/quieras/bin/activate
```

o el siguiente en windows (cmd):

```
C:/ruta/a/la/carpeta/que/quieras/Scripts/activate.bat
```

En cualquiera de los casos tu *prompt* cambiará para recordarte que estás "en un entorno virtual". En realidad simplemente se ha cambiado el PATH para que el python que se use sea el de ese entorno.

Una vez tienes el entorno activado, poniendo `python` a secas estarás usando el intérprete de ese entorno, y poniendo `pip install` estarás instalando cosas en ese entorno.

Si usas VSCode como IDE, éste tiene soporte integrado para detectar entornos virtuales (si los creas en una carpeta llamada `venvs` dentro de tu carpeta de usuario) y para activar uno de ellos mientras trabajas con el editor, para que el autocompletado y la ayuda se basen en los paquetes instalados en ese entorno virtual.